# IntersectionObserverAPI Return to default state when none of the elements are visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I'm using a React Hook to detect when an element is visible in the viewport. Until then, everything works fine but I need to 'reset' the state when everything is hidden (like reaching the footer or the header).

Here's my hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

const useIntersect = (ref) => {
  const [isOnScreen, setIsOnScreen] = useState(false)
  const observerRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
      setIsOnScreen(entry.isIntersecting)
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    observerRef.current.observe(ref.current)
    return () => observerRef.current.disconnect()
  }, [ref])

  return isOnScreen
}

export default useIntersect
```

And here's the state I'm updating:

```
  const elementRef = useRef(null)
  const[state, setState] = useState('nothing is visible')
  const onScreen = useIntersect(elementRef)

  useEffect(() => {
    return onScreen ? setState('an item is visible') : null
  })

  return (
    <Item ref={elementRef}>
      ...
    </Item>
  )
```

I need to be able to say `setState('...')` to something (let's say a string) when all the elements are off the viewport (when the condition onScreen is not met) but even when I reach the footer when nothing is visible, it keeps the last item in memory.

I've tried many things but I cannot figure a way out :(

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your `useIntersect` hook should add a dependency on the `ref.current` instead of `ref` for the second `useEffect`

so

```
useEffect(() => {
  observerRef.current.observe(ref.current)
  return () => observerRef.current.disconnect()
}, [ref.current]);
```

and then when using it in the component do

```
useEffect(() => {
  return onScreen ? setState('an item is visible') : setState('nothing is visible');
}, [onScreen])
```

you should add a dependency on the `onScreen` so it only updates when the `onScreen` has changed, and lastly you should call `setState` for the scenario when the `onScreen` is false to the value you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It worked great when I added these options to `IntersectionObserver` with your solution:
`const options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '50%',
    threshold: 1.0
  }`

Otherwise, it struggles to detect which item is on screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with how you are passing elementRef to the hook.

useIntersect useEffect will not execute when elementRef changes.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const useIntersect = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [isOnScreen, setIsOnScreen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref) {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) =>
        setIsOnScreen(entry.isIntersecting)
      );
      observer.observe(ref.current);
      return () => observer.disconnect();
    }
  }, [ref]);

  return [isOnScreen, ref];
};

export default useIntersect;

// -----------------------------Component-------------------------------
const [state, setState] = useState("nothing is visible");
const [onScreen, elementRef] = useIntersect();

useEffect(() => {
  return onScreen ? setState("an item is visible") : null;
});

return <Item ref={elementRef}></Item>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think there's a problem with your code where you declare `ref` in the hook but pass none in the useIntersect() parentheses.

Comment: @user990463 yes that's correct, it was typo

Comment: Hm, it still doesn't work. When I tried your code, the state doesn't change anymore

Answer (score 1):

Your hook implementation seems fine. you might want to recheck the height of the `Item` component.
check this code sandbox working fine with your hook implementation
: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-wood-ruks2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks! That's a good way to check the height of an item :)